# Construct PRG from PRF with polynomial expansion factor

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

I want to prove that for every pseudorandom function $F: \{0, 1\}^n \times \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^n$ and for every polynomial $p$ such that $p(n) > 1$ for every $n$ it is possible to construct, starting from $F$, a pseudorandom generator $G$ having expansion factor equal to $l(n) = p(n) \cdot n$.

I fixed a PRF $F$ and came up with two constructions for $G$ (where || denotes the concatenation of binary strings), but I am not sure of either:

1. $G(k) = F_k(0^n) || F_k(F_k(0^n))|| \cdots || F_k(...(F_k(0^n))$.

The idea is to apply $F_k$ to the previous output $p(n)$ times. I'm not sure if this is indeed a PRG, though. I fear that in some cases it could lead to "cyclic" strings, but I am not sure.

2. $G(k) = F_k(000...000) || F_k(000...001)|| \cdots || F_k(111...111)$

In the second construction all the inputs have length $n$ and the final output has length $n \cdot 2^n$, but for some combination of $n$ and $p$ the output cannot have a length of $p(n)\cdot n$. For instance, if $n = 2$ and $p(n) = n^{100}+1$, then $|G(k)|= 8$ which is less than $2^{100} + 1$.

Could anyone give me a hint to push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper construction is one similar to your second one.

Once fixed $l(n)=p(n)\cdot n$ you can construct a PRF $G$ with expansion factor $l(n)$ from a PRF $F:\{0, 1\}^n \times \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^n$ in the following way:

$G(k) = F_k(1) || F_k(2) || ... || F_k(p(n))$.

You can prove that $G$ is a PRG since if you replace the PRF $F$ with a true random function $f$ and define $G'(k) = f(1) || f(2) || ... || f(p(n))$ an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ that distinguish $G'$ from $G$ can be used to distinguish $F$ from $f$ contradicting the fact that $F$ is a PRF.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your PRG constructions are secure.

- Your first construction is essentially [output feedback mode (OFB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)). It is the OFB encryption of the all-zeroes plaintext.
- Similarly, your second construction is essentially a [counter mode (CTR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) encryption of the all-zeroes plaintext.

Both OFB and CTR modes are CPA-secure. This doesn't exactly guarantee that the PRGs are secure (because the PRGs use these modes with all-zeroes IV), but the proofs of CPA security can be easily adapted to show that both of your PRGs are secure.